# Load Balancing a UDP server

Tags: networking, load, system, load-balancing

> #### Asked on Server Fault:
>
> #### [Load Balancing a UDP server](https://serverfault.com/questions/228794/load-balancing-a-udp-server)

I have a udp server, it is a central part in my business process. in order to handle the loads I'm expecting in the production environment ill probably need 2 or 3 instances of the server. The server is almost entirely stateless, it mostly collect's data, and the layer above it knows how to handle the minimal amount of stale data that can arise from the the multiple server instances.

My question is how can I implement load balancing between the servers? I would prefer to distribute the requests as evenly as possible between the servers. I would also would like to have some fidelity, i mean if client X was routed to server y, then I want all of X's subsequent requests to go to server Y, as long as it is sensible and not overloads Y.

By the way it is a .NET system...
what would you recommend?

Comment: Should possibly be on serverfault?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/228794/load-balancing-a-udp-server

Answer (score 4):

How many clients will be using these servers? If the number is reasonably high [DNS round robin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_DNS) loadbalancing would probably be fine.

Comment: Not all clients are using DNS servers that do round robin - but since this is UDP the OP probably controls the client and can do random selection in the client

Comment: im expecting 50K but they dont have DNS... only IP...

Comment: @Hellfrost it's your DNS server (mainly) that must do round-robin.

Comment: :-\ it all works within a LAN, we dont want nor need DNS. anything comming from the WAN will just be pointed at a NAT sending to communication to us, and we dont expect anything from the WAN anytime soon...

Comment: Hard code a list of ip addresses then and randomly pick one every packet or execution as appropriate.

Comment: @awoodland: i can't i didnt write the component sending the traffic. And that wouldn't be wise because i want my client to be completely oblivious to all this. look at the link i posted to server fault, in the comment to my question.